# Fields of static objects become null when home button is pressed

Tags: android, singleton, android-broadcast, android-memory

In my app, I inject some singleton manager objects using dagger.

Suppose one of these managers, say myManager, keeps data in a list, say myList.
Also I have a BroadcastReceiver class, say myBroadcastReceiver which calls one of myManager methods, say myMethod, when it receives some particular intents.

If I open my app and wait until myList is initialized, then press home, and after that myBroadcastReceiver receives the intent and calls myMethod, myList is null (though myManager itself is not null).

I can't figure if it's a matter of android's natural behavior or if I've actually made a mistake that it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think your singleton class is getting unloaded due to low memory you need to save that list in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) and retrieve the same in onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

You could either implement a "save state" solution using onSaveIntanceState functionality provided by android in your activity or service or whatever component you're using

Or you can save your data locally in a file or even better a sqlite database, which could be very simple and straight forward to implement.

And by keeping your list "in memory" synch'd with the local storage, you'll never lose any data.

Simply using lazy loading, each time your list is null, fetch the data back from local storage.